# How to filter data using routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter, parameters, routes

i am new to laravel. i have table called "countries" in database. and have three columns . so how do i can pass filters with route url to get filtered data 
Example : Adding ?name=spain to endpoint will only return entries where name column has value set to spain.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with something like this:

```
Route::get('country/{country}', function($country) {
    $countries = \App\Country::where('name',$country)->get();
    view('yourview', compact('countries');
});
```

and then use the url http://yourdomain.com/country/spain

Comment: thnx for the reply but this is what i get             Builder {#180 ▼
  #query: Builder {#179 ▶}
  #model: Countries {#184 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:12 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}

Comment: sorry, yes, I have updated my answer with ```->get()``` which will return the collection of results that you can use, eg. ```$countries->toArray();```, depends on your needs

Comment: hey CuGreen thnx now i am getting a array like this  Collection {#189 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Countries {#191 ▼
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 20
        "name" => "Spain"
        "iso2" => "ES"
        "iso3" => "ESP"
        "created_at" => "2018-03-31 19:16:36"
        "updated_at" => "2018-03-31 19:16:36"
      ] how do i display this attributes in my view?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example with a view. As I said it will depend on your needs.

Comment: voila !! \thnx a lot

Comment: No problems. Feel free to mark it correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request()->get('name')` because you have a route with `?name=spain` witch is a query get param.

In your case, you can try this:

```
Route::get('countries', function() {
    $countries = \App\Country::where('name',request()->get('name'))->get();
    dd($countries);
});
```

Comment: yeh i tried that so for example http://localhost:8000/?name=spain it lands me to home page any idea whts wrong here

Comment: How have you declare your route ?
You are here in `/`path so laravel redirects you to home

Comment: yeh i got that thnx a lot yebor974